# C# Adding selected value form combobox to array

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I want to send the `Combobox.SelectedValue` as a new element into an array.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {   
        Combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
        Combobox.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
        Combobox.Items.Add(new { Text = "String", Value = 7 });
        Combobox.Items.Add(new { Text = "String", Value = 2 });

        ClassName[] array = ClassName[30];
        array[0] = Combobox.SelectedValue();
}
```

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: Do you want to send the selected value based on a button click or when it should happen ?

Comment: Yes based on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot implicitly cast a SelectedValue return type (string) to ClassName. If you change your array to a string array string[] array, your code should work

Comment: You can also add a new ClassName element to the array if you have the required variables.

Comment: public class ClassName
{ 
     public string SomeString{get;set;}
}
 array[0].SomeString = Combobox.SelectedValue();